# How do I call child node elements from a parent node?

Tags: theming, nodes

Let's say I have two content types. A content type for parent node and a content type for child node. I need to render selected child nodes in the parent node.

How can I achieve this using Twig? In Drupal 7, I have created a view and access them from PHP code. How can I do this in Drupal 8?

Comment: What defines the parent/child relationship between these nodes?

Comment: From the taxonomy